# Get TelegramBot Poll Result

Tags: python, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api, telebot

I need to have the results of a telegramBot Polls. How to get them from the bot and not the group, since it will questions the users separately and individually. i want to score them.
Regards
Jeff Kh.

I can't get the result.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.